# Why does Arduino only run my loop twice when communicating with the serial port?

Tags: python, c++, arduino, io, serial-port

Long story short, I am trying to use the Arduino as an IO module, and this code is for writing values to the digital and analogue outports. The commands are sent through the serial port bytewise(to reduce lagging) from a Python program, hence the weird structure.

My problem now is that for some reason, Arduino can read two commands (one at a time) and then it stops. No errors or anything, it just doesn't do anything, and I cannot figure out where my mistake is for the life of it.

The messages are structured as three bytes with x's as the separator. The first indicates if the outport is analogue `o` or digital `p`, the second defines the channel number, and the last the value that is to be sent to said channel. Example: `ox2x50` means A2 should be set to 50%.

BTW: This is just a snippet of a more extensive program, so atm I'm simply typing the commands in the serial port.

Can anyone tell me why it only runs twice?

```
/* Still in development, hence the excessive amount of printing commands*/

const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
String stringpart;
String sortedData[3];

boolean newData = false;

// Declare outputs
const int DO0 = 2;
const int DO1 = 4;
const int DO2 = 7;
const int DO3 = 8;

const int AO0 =3;
const int AO1 =5;
const int AO2 =6;
const int AO3 =9;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    //Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
    pinMode(DO0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DO1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DO2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DO3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(AO0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(AO1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(AO2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(AO3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()>0){           // Return the number of bytes available on serial. if <0, = no info on serial.

  
    recvWithEndMarker();
    showNewData();
    analogueOut();     //NB! Resets newdata
    //readarray = recvWithEndMarker();

    
  }//If serial available
}

// Reads from recial port until \n is received.
String recvWithEndMarker() {
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char endMarker = '\n';
    char rc;
    
    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (rc != endMarker) {
            receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
            ndx++;
            if (ndx >= numChars) {
                ndx = numChars - 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string

            // Extracting each vlaue split by X
            for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {                       // Only runs 3 times, as it needs to extract 1.A or D 2.ChNo and 3. Value
               sortedData[j] = splitValue(receivedChars,'x',j);   // Extracts the j number position  
            }// for loop

            for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {                       // Only for test printing
               Serial.println(sortedData[i]);  
            }// for loop

            ndx = 0;                                      // Reset counter
            newData = true;                               // Inform that new data has arrived

        }
    }

 
}

// Simply prints what's recieved
void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        //Serial.print("This just in ... ");
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        
        
    }
}

// Splits the received string into its separate characters and stores them in array
String splitValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = {0, -1};
  int maxIndex = data.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=maxIndex && found<=index; i++){
    if(data.charAt(i)==separator || i==maxIndex){
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1]+1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}


// Function to convert ASCII symbol to integer. For sortData[2] 
int stringInt(char recievedVal){ 

    int y = int(recievedVal);                     // Converts ASCII character to corresponding integers  0-100 

    int finalVal = constrain((map(y, 0, 100, 0, 255)), 0, 255);  //Converts 0-100(recieved as char) to 0-255 
    
    Serial.println("Recieved value: "); 
    Serial.println(finalVal);           // Print value between 0-255.    
 
} // stringInt function 



// Functino to (hopefully) split and convert recieved data into something useful

String analogueOut() { // Use sortedData as input, writes to analogue outputs

  if (newData == true) {
    // Result in an array with two elements. One A1/D2 etc and one Value/onoff

    int channel = (sortedData[1]).toInt();   // Converts the number recieved in channel number to an int
    char chVal = (sortedData[2]).toInt();    // Converts the number recieved in channel Val to an int which is then converted to a char
    int chValConv = stringInt(chVal);        // Sends the char chVal to string toInt function, returned scaled and converted to int.
  

    if (sortedData[0] == "o") {
      //Serial.println("Analogue");

      switch (channel) {
          case 1:
            Serial.println("AO0");
            analogWrite(AO0, chValConv);
          break;
          case 2:
            Serial.println("AO1");
            analogWrite(AO1, chValConv);
          break;
          case 3:
            Serial.println("AO2");
            analogWrite(AO2, chValConv);
          break;
          case 4:
            Serial.println("AO3");
            analogWrite(AO3, chValConv);
          break;
          default:
            Serial.println("NaN");
          break;
      } // Switch case channel
      
    } // if recievedArray[0]=o

    else if (sortedData[0] == "p") {
      //Serial.println("Digital");

      switch (channel) {
          case 1:
            Serial.println("DO0");
            analogWrite(DO0, chValConv);
          break;
          case 2:
            Serial.println("DO1");
            analogWrite(DO1, chValConv);
          break;
          case 3:
            Serial.println("DO2");
            analogWrite(DO2, chValConv);
          break;
          case 4:
            Serial.println("DO3");
            analogWrite(DO3, chValConv);
          break;
          default:
            Serial.println("NaN");
          break;
      } // Switch case channel
    
    } // if recievedArray[0]=p 

    else {
      Serial.println("Not valid");
    } // if recievedArray[0]=p 

    
    newData = false;
  } // if newData True
  
} // String analogueOut
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is the Strings are fragmenting the heap, which keeps growing and then collides with the stack, see for example [Taming Arduino Strings](https://www.instructables.com/Taming-Arduino-Strings-How-to-Avoid-Memory-Issues/#:%7E:text=Arduino%20Strings%20use%20heap%20memory,discarded%2C%20it%20leaves%20a%20hole.).  That article has lots of good tips but the important takeaway is try to reduce the number of Strings you use and don't pass as many Strings as arguments or return as many Strings from functions (even your *recvWithEndMarker* and *analogueOut* functions were returning unused Strings).  You can use String functions but you have to be careful about how long the Strings hang around.  You can see I used String functions in the parseData function but I only had one String and the function wasn't being called repeatedly by another function with String variables.

My suggestions for your code are to keep the global character buffer *receivedChars* you were already using but move your buffer index *ndx* to be a global: this lets you parse that data in another function without passing it around as an argument.  I would also remove the global String array *String sortedData[3]* and instead make three globals for the values (1 char and 2 ints) you are interested in.  The code below runs without hanging after two iterations of input.

```
/* Still in development, hence the excessive amount of printing commands*/

const byte numChars = 16;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
byte ndx = 0;
boolean newData = false;

char analogDigital;
int channel;   // Converts the number recieved in channel number to an int
char chVal;    // Converts the number recieved in channel Val to an int which is then converted to a char
int chValConv; // Sends the char chVal to string toInt function, returned scaled and converted to int.


// Declare outputs
const int DO0 = 2;
const int DO1 = 4;
const int DO2 = 7;
const int DO3 = 8;

const int AO0 = 3;
const int AO1 = 5;
const int AO2 = 6;
const int AO3 = 9;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
  pinMode(DO0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DO1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DO2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DO3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AO0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AO1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AO2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AO3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {       // Return the number of bytes available on serial. if <0, = no info on serial.
    recvWithEndMarker();
    analogueOut();     //NB! Resets newdata
  }//If serial available
}

// Reads from Serial port until \n is received.
void recvWithEndMarker() {
  char endMarker = '\n';
  char rc;
  boolean done = false;

  while (Serial.available() && !done) {
    rc = Serial.read();
    if (rc == endMarker) {
      done = true;
      newData  = true;
    }
    else {
      receivedChars[ndx++] = rc;
      if (ndx >= numChars)
        done = true;
    }
  }

  if (newData) {
    if (!parseInput()) { // if we call parseData it fails there is no need to process that data further.
      Serial.println("string couldn't be parsed");
      newData = false;
    }
    ndx = 0;
  }
}


// Splits the received string into its separate characters and stores them in globals
boolean parseInput() {
  int secondX = -1;
  String tempString;

  for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
    Serial.print(receivedChars[i]);
  Serial.println();

  if (receivedChars[1] != 'x')
    return false;
  else {
    analogDigital = receivedChars[0];

    for (int i = 3; i < ndx && secondX == -1; i++)
      if (receivedChars[i] == 'x')
        secondX = i;

    if (secondX == -1)
      return false;

    tempString = receivedChars;
    channel = tempString.substring(2, secondX).toInt();
    chValConv = tempString.substring(secondX + 1, ndx).toInt();
    chValConv = constrain((map(chValConv, 0, 100, 0, 255)), 0, 255);  //Converts 0-100(recieved as char) to 0-255

    Serial.print("analogDigital -> ");
    Serial.println(analogDigital);
    Serial.print("channel -> ");
    Serial.println(channel);
    Serial.print("chValConv -> ");
    Serial.println(chValConv);
  }
  return true;
}

void analogueOut() { // Writes to analogue outputs

  if (newData == true) {
    // Result in an array with two elements. One A1/D2 etc and one Value/onoff

    if (analogDigital == 'o') {
      //Serial.println("Analogue");

      switch (channel) {
        case 1:
          Serial.println("AO0");
          analogWrite(AO0, chValConv);
          break;
        case 2:
          Serial.println("AO1");
          analogWrite(AO1, chValConv);
          break;
        case 3:
          Serial.println("AO2");
          analogWrite(AO2, chValConv);
          break;
        case 4:
          Serial.println("AO3");
          analogWrite(AO3, chValConv);
          break;
        default:
          Serial.println("NaN");
          break;
      } // Switch case channel

    } // if recievedArray[0]=o

    else if (analogDigital == 'p') {
      //Serial.println("Digital");

      switch (channel) {
        case 1:
          Serial.println("DO0");
          analogWrite(DO0, chValConv);
          break;
        case 2:
          Serial.println("DO1");
          analogWrite(DO1, chValConv);
          break;
        case 3:
          Serial.println("DO2");
          analogWrite(DO2, chValConv);
          break;
        case 4:
          Serial.println("DO3");
          analogWrite(DO3, chValConv);
          break;
        default:
          Serial.println("NaN");
          break;
      } // Switch case channel

    } // if recievedArray[0]=p

    else {
      Serial.println("Not valid");
    } // if recievedArray[0]=p


    newData = false;
  } // if newData True

} // String analogueOut
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks a million mate!! I'm fairly new to Arduino and Cish-coding in general, so I was not aware strings could cause such problems. I'll be careful with them from now on. Thank you very much!